# How Do I Convert Partial Mocks From Mockito to JMockit?

Tags: mockito, jmockit

I had some test code using Mockito (see below), however, I think I need to switch to the more powerful JMockit to achieve my test.

However, if I use the `@Tested`annotation on the Session class, the init method called from the constructor throws an Exception.

If I use `@Mocked` on the Session class I don't have the real methods available to test.

What is not shown below is that I will also need access to the `details` object during the test. However, this is retrieved from the `plugin` object during the constructor and the constructor calls the problematic `init` method.

How do I test the `checkDetails` method with JMockit?

**Test Code**

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SessionTest {

    @Test
    public void testSession() {
        Session session = Mockito.mock(Session.class);
        Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(session).checkDetails(Mockito.any(String.class));

        Assert.assertEquals(session.checkDetails("Foo"), true);
    }

}
```

**Class to test**

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.List;

public class Session {
    private final Socket socket;
    private final List<String> details;
    private final Plugin plugin;

    public Session(Socket socket, Plugin plugin) throws SocketException {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.plugin = plugin;
        this.details = plugin.getDetails();
        init();
    }

    public void init() throws SocketException {
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
    }

    public boolean checkDetails(String item) {
        for (String detail : details) {
            if (detail.equals(item)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Dependency**

```
import java.util.List;

public class Plugin {
    private List<String> details;

    public List<String> getDetails() {
        return details;
    }
}
```

**Note:** This is a very much simplified version of the code and changing the production code is not possible at this time.

Comment: [Partial mocking](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html#partial) and [proceeding into the real implementation in a "fake"](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Faking.html#proceed) are both clearly documented in the JMockit manual, so perhaps you should be a little more clear about what is causing you problems?

Answer (score 0):

I would not run this test with partial mocking, personally. This is not a case where you would want to partially mock your code-under-test. (I only mock the CUT in cases where I have a utility method I am independently testing, and I want to assume that utility method works just fine, and test the larger context. You are not doing that here.)

I would take one of two tacks, depending on exactly what my goals were.

#### Option One

Treat the constructor as part of what you are testing:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class SessionTest {

    @Injectable Socket socket;
    @Injectable Plugin plugin;

    @Test
    public void testCheckDetails() throws Exception {
        new Expectations() {{
            plugin.getDetails(); result = Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar", "Baz");
        }};

        Session session = new Session(socket, plugin);


        boolean b = session.checkDetails("Foo");
        assertThat(b, is(true));

    }
}
```

#### Option Two

Assume the object was constructed properly and has its `List<String> details` field initialized properly.

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class SessionTest {

    @Tested
    Session cut;

    @Injectable Socket socket;
    @Injectable Plugin plugin;

    @Test
    public void testCheckDetails() throws Exception {
        List<String> details = Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar", "Baz");
        Deencapsulation.setField(cut, details);

        boolean b = cut.checkDetails("Foo");
        assertThat(b, is(true));
    }
}
```

#### Actual Partial Mocking

If this doesn't cut it and you really have your heart set on partial mocking (e.g. you haven't given the full story and you really need to do it), here's how it would work. Let's suppose we have one more method on `Session`:

```
public List<String> getDetails() {
    return plugin.getDetails();
}
```

and let's further assume that `checkDetails` consults this helper method rather than a field in your instance.

```
public boolean checkDetails(String item) {
    for (String detail : getDetails()) {
        if (detail.equals(item)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then a test using partial mocking might look like this:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class SessionTest {

    @Tested
    Session cut;

    @Injectable Socket socket;
    @Injectable Plugin plugin;

    @Test
    public void testCheckDetails() throws Exception {
        new Expectations(cut) {
            {
                cut.getDetails(); result=Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar", "Baz");
            }
        };

        boolean b = cut.checkDetails("Foo");
        assertThat(b, is(true));
    }
}
```

#### Faking It

Alternatively, you can use a fake. Again, same assumptions of a `getDetails()` method as in the last section:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class SessionTest {

    @Tested
    Session cut;

    @Injectable Socket socket;
    @Injectable Plugin plugin;

    @Test
    public void testCheckDetails() throws Exception {
        new MockUp<Session>() {
            @Mock
            List<String> getDetails() {
                return Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar", "Baz");
            }
        };

        Session cut = new Session(socket, plugin);

        boolean b = cut.checkDetails("Foo");
        assertThat(b, is(true));
    }
}
```

#### Final Words

Note that in all cases, when you start to partially mock or fake an object, then the default action is to do the real implementation for that partial mock or fake. Only methods explicitly mocked/faked will be, well, mocked or faked. This is in contrast to the Mockito method you use where there's an explicit `doCallRealMethod()` (and you would be calling a mocked method without it).

Also, the `assertThat(...)` stuff is not part of JMockit; it's part of JUnit and is just how I like to do my tests, and I'm too lazy to go back and change it to the assertions you had.

Comment: My assertions are different because I'm using the superior TestNG :p The key thing in the question though is that the Session constructor calls an init method which throws an exception and will do in all of your examples too. It is a good explanation though and helped me make it work.

Comment: It's declared as throwing an exception, but because the `Socket` object is mocked in all of my examples, the exception won't actually get thrown. `socket.setTcpNoDelay()` will be a no-op. You can, of course, use the partial-mocking or faking example to add `init()` to the methods you mock, but in this simple example it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The JMockit equivalent to `Session session = Mockito.mock(Session.class);` is either

```
Session session = new MockUp<Session>() {}.getMockInstance();
```

or

```
@Mock
Session session;
```

As mentioned in answer by @dcsohl there isn't a direct equivalent of `Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(session).checkDetails(Mockito.any(String.class));`

However, you can use the `MockUp` approach to use all real methods and then specify a method to exclude. In this case the `init` method was the main reason for mocking and what we needed to exclude from being called.

```
new MockUp<Session>() {
    @Mock
    public void init() {
        //Don't call the real init
    }
};

session = new Session(mockPlugin, mockSocket);
```

Note that in this case we don't call `getMockInstance` on the MockUp. However, JMockit will create the Mock when we all the contstructor in the next line.